# Precompiling assets with capistrano gives error during deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3, digital-ocean, precompile-assets

I am trying to deploy my rails app to a digital ocean server using the capistrano gem, and I'm getting the error :

```
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Command::Failed: RAILS_ENV= bundle exec rake assets:precompile exit status: 256
RAILS_ENV= bundle exec rake assets:precompile stdout: Nothing written
RAILS_ENV= bundle exec rake assets:precompile stderr: rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter
```

Even though the local config/database.yml and shared/config/database.yml file on the server are both configured, and have production databases set.
In case I run the rake db:create command on the server, it does create the database successfully. So, can't really find the issue.

Using rails 4.0.2, ruby 2.1.0, capsitrano 3.1.0

Comment: Kindly post your database.yml file without the password and the username ofcourse.

Comment: That blank RAILS_ENV isn't right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - I don't have the rep to comment.
It's a bit short on detail about your deploy configuration, you probably need to share.

```
RAILS_ENV= bundle exec rake assets:precompile stdout: Nothing written
```

Would suggest to me that there is no RAILS_ENV set. I don't think there is an issue with the database .yml

Infact - this post might be relevant: [Capistrano 3, Rails 4, database configuration does not specify adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599986/capistrano-3-rails-4-database-configuration-does-not-specify-adapter)

Comment: right.. i think i missed that out... The precompiling still doesnt work... 'Sprockets::ArgumentError: Asset logical path has no extension: admin/table_demo'

Comment: That's a different issue I think see: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/347 - has the table_demo file not got an extension? try renaming it.

Comment: ok, but this still leads to the following :
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...":3,"sources":[": expected "|", was ""less/normalize..."

Comment: Suggest you post up as a new question.. my immediate thought is that your CSS is invalid as per the error message - I'm not sure if that is caused by renaming the file though - does it still work locally with the rename? Does the css refer to the file without the extension..