# Rails 4 Capistrano Still uses old release after Deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, capistrano, linode

I'm working with a project that someone else built and configured. I cloned their GitHub repository and have changed the references in deploy.rb to pull from my repo.

I made some fixes to the application and pushed to my repository. Then ran `bundle exec cap production deploy`. The site is still using the old code. What else do I need to do? The newly deployed version shows up in the "releases" folder. The "current" softlink points to the old code, but changing it to the new release doesn't do anything.

Please help. This is a huge waste of time. Thanks.

**EDIT**: Log output from running `bundle exec cap production deploy`..

```
ThinkPad-L412:~/projects/programservices$ bundle exec cap production deploy
DEBUG [0634a583] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5 ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [0634a583] Command: [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5 ]
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
deployer@45.56.119.188's password:???????
DEBUG [0634a583] Finished in 13.330 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [a4a516db] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/programservices/ as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [a4a516db] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/programservices/ )
INFO [a4a516db] Finished in 0.058 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/programservices/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
INFO Uploading /tmp/programservices/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO [e12b8559] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/programservices/git-ssh.sh as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [e12b8559] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/programservices/git-ssh.sh )
INFO [e12b8559] Finished in 0.063 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [73c708ef] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:bbulpett/programservices.git as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [73c708ef] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/programservices/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:bbulpett/programservices.git )
DEBUG [73c708ef]    ab8f7c2703c6e40d6c265c312b8c361bd5af967b    HEAD
DEBUG [73c708ef]    ab8f7c2703c6e40d6c265c312b8c361bd5af967b    refs/heads/master
DEBUG [73c708ef] Finished in 0.469 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [d88fccf2] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deployer/programservices/shared /home/deployer/programservices/releases as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [d88fccf2] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deployer/programservices/shared /home/deployer/programservices/releases )
INFO [d88fccf2] Finished in 0.072 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [7094084e] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deployer/programservices/shared/log /home/deployer/programservices/shared/tmp/pids /home/deployer/programservices/shared/tmp/cache /home/deployer/programservices/shared/tmp/sockets /home/deployer/programservices/shared/vendor/bundle /home/deployer/programservices/shared/public/system /home/deployer/programservices/shared/public/uploads /home/deployer/programservices/shared/public/assets as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [7094084e] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deployer/programservices/shared/log /home/deployer/programservices/shared/tmp/pids /home/deployer/programservices/shared/tmp/cache /home/deployer/programservices/shared/tmp/sockets /home/deployer/programservices/shared/vendor/bundle /home/deployer/programservices/shared/public/system /home/deployer/programservices/shared/public/uploads /home/deployer/programservices/shared/public/assets )
INFO [7094084e] Finished in 0.060 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [875ecaea] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deployer/programservices/shared/config /home/deployer/programservices/shared as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [875ecaea] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deployer/programservices/shared/config /home/deployer/programservices/shared )
INFO [875ecaea] Finished in 0.062 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [67e3bcee] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/deployer/programservices/shared/config/database.yml ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [67e3bcee] Command: [ -f /home/deployer/programservices/shared/config/database.yml ]
DEBUG [67e3bcee] Finished in 0.060 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [b95ab732] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/deployer/programservices/shared/.rbenv-vars ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [b95ab732] Command: [ -f /home/deployer/programservices/shared/.rbenv-vars ]
DEBUG [b95ab732] Finished in 0.063 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [23b630c0] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/deployer/programservices/repo/HEAD ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [23b630c0] Command: [ -f /home/deployer/programservices/repo/HEAD ]
DEBUG [23b630c0] Finished in 0.057 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO The repository mirror is at /home/deployer/programservices/repo
DEBUG [b1bf3187] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /home/deployer/programservices/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/programservices/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [b1bf3187] Command: if test ! -d /home/deployer/programservices/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/programservices/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [b1bf3187] Finished in 0.064 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [a73e4ce4] Running /usr/bin/env cd /home/deployer/programservices/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [a73e4ce4] Command: cd /home/deployer/programservices/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD
DEBUG [a73e4ce4]    00c39b3
DEBUG [a73e4ce4] Finished in 0.064 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [807acc5c] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [807acc5c] Command: cd /home/deployer/programservices/repo && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env git remote update )
DEBUG [807acc5c]    Fetching origin
DEBUG [807acc5c]    From github.com:bbulpett/programservices
DEBUG [807acc5c]       00c39b3..ab8f7c2  master     -> master
INFO [807acc5c] Finished in 0.592 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [c9aab581] Running /usr/bin/env cd /home/deployer/programservices/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [c9aab581] Command: cd /home/deployer/programservices/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD
DEBUG [c9aab581]    ab8f7c2
DEBUG [c9aab581] Finished in 0.061 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [ca421bdf] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /home/deployer/programservices/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/programservices/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [ca421bdf] Command: if test ! -d /home/deployer/programservices/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/programservices/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [ca421bdf] Finished in 0.057 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [8db23646] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310 as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [8db23646] Command: cd /home/deployer/programservices/repo && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/programservices/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310 )
INFO [8db23646] Finished in 0.064 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [c26205f6] Running /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -C /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310 as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [c26205f6] Command: cd /home/deployer/programservices/repo && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/programservices/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -C /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310 )
INFO [c26205f6] Finished in 0.509 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [634ca844] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/config /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310 as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [634ca844] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/config /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310 )
INFO [634ca844] Finished in 0.062 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [925ebb92] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/config/database.yml ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [925ebb92] Command: [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/config/database.yml ]
DEBUG [925ebb92] Finished in 0.059 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [157f183a] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/config/database.yml ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [157f183a] Command: [ -f /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/config/database.yml ]
DEBUG [157f183a] Finished in 0.057 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [f7481261] Running /usr/bin/env rm /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/config/database.yml as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [f7481261] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env rm /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/config/database.yml )
INFO [f7481261] Finished in 0.060 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [8761c8bf] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/config/database.yml /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/config/database.yml as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [8761c8bf] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/config/database.yml /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/config/database.yml )
INFO [8761c8bf] Finished in 0.068 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [e0b0a6d2] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/.rbenv-vars ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [e0b0a6d2] Command: [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/.rbenv-vars ]
DEBUG [e0b0a6d2] Finished in 0.059 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [14db68a7] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/.rbenv-vars ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [14db68a7] Command: [ -f /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/.rbenv-vars ]
DEBUG [14db68a7] Finished in 0.061 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO [f18839d0] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/.rbenv-vars /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/.rbenv-vars as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [f18839d0] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/.rbenv-vars /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/.rbenv-vars )
INFO [f18839d0] Finished in 0.061 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [7ca506a6] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310 /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/vendor /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [7ca506a6] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310 /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/vendor /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public )
INFO [7ca506a6] Finished in 0.061 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [dfc70755] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/log ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [dfc70755] Command: [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/log ]
DEBUG [dfc70755] Finished in 0.060 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [a8178276] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/log ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [a8178276] Command: [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/log ]
DEBUG [a8178276] Finished in 0.055 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [6a707866] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/log as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [6a707866] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/log )
INFO [6a707866] Finished in 0.063 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [35fd265e] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/log /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/log as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [35fd265e] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/log /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/log )
INFO [35fd265e] Finished in 0.062 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [e02cb3b1] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/pids ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [e02cb3b1] Command: [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/pids ]
DEBUG [e02cb3b1] Finished in 0.060 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [008b24ea] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/pids ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [008b24ea] Command: [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/pids ]
DEBUG [008b24ea] Finished in 0.090 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO [3a61bccd] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/tmp/pids /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/pids as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [3a61bccd] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/tmp/pids /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/pids )
INFO [3a61bccd] Finished in 0.060 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [e1bcbd1c] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/cache ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [e1bcbd1c] Command: [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/cache ]
DEBUG [e1bcbd1c] Finished in 0.060 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [e7fc2ac8] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/cache ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [e7fc2ac8] Command: [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/cache ]
DEBUG [e7fc2ac8] Finished in 0.059 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [46202405] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/cache as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [46202405] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/cache )
INFO [46202405] Finished in 0.088 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [68cfe2df] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/tmp/cache /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/cache as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [68cfe2df] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/tmp/cache /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/cache )
INFO [68cfe2df] Finished in 0.063 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [808d98bf] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/sockets ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [808d98bf] Command: [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/sockets ]
DEBUG [808d98bf] Finished in 0.058 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [ff190950] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/sockets ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [ff190950] Command: [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/sockets ]
DEBUG [ff190950] Finished in 0.062 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO [b70cc18d] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/tmp/sockets /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/sockets as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [b70cc18d] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/tmp/sockets /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/tmp/sockets )
INFO [b70cc18d] Finished in 0.064 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [2e607f2e] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/vendor/bundle ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [2e607f2e] Command: [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/vendor/bundle ]
DEBUG [2e607f2e] Finished in 0.059 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [f3db1877] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/vendor/bundle ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [f3db1877] Command: [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/vendor/bundle ]
DEBUG [f3db1877] Finished in 0.058 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO [1c7428ea] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/vendor/bundle /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/vendor/bundle as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [1c7428ea] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/vendor/bundle /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/vendor/bundle )
INFO [1c7428ea] Finished in 0.060 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [cab985d6] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/system ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [cab985d6] Command: [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/system ]
DEBUG [cab985d6] Finished in 0.060 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [8aa30e54] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/system ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [8aa30e54] Command: [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/system ]
DEBUG [8aa30e54] Finished in 0.057 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO [06c24b49] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/public/system /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/system as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [06c24b49] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/public/system /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/system )
INFO [06c24b49] Finished in 0.063 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [4465e9ac] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/uploads ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [4465e9ac] Command: [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/uploads ]
DEBUG [4465e9ac] Finished in 0.061 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [75dd3879] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/uploads ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [75dd3879] Command: [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/uploads ]
DEBUG [75dd3879] Finished in 0.057 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO [f7475256] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/public/uploads /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/uploads as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [f7475256] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/public/uploads /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/uploads )
INFO [f7475256] Finished in 0.062 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [b2e91c7a] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/assets ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [b2e91c7a] Command: [ -L /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/assets ]
DEBUG [b2e91c7a] Finished in 0.060 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [6bcdc73c] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/assets ] as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [6bcdc73c] Command: [ -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/assets ]
DEBUG [6bcdc73c] Finished in 0.061 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [cfee9f81] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/assets as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [cfee9f81] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/assets )
INFO [cfee9f81] Finished in 0.077 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [7240892f] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/public/assets /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/assets as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [7240892f] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deployer/programservices/shared/public/assets /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/public/assets )
INFO [7240892f] Finished in 0.062 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [c1dc9241] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310'" 1>&2; false; fi as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [c1dc9241] Command: if test ! -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [c1dc9241] Finished in 0.053 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [12caea9e] Running ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [12caea9e] Command: cd /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310 && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )
INFO [12caea9e] Finished in 84.762 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [d80966a6] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310'" 1>&2; false; fi as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [d80966a6] Command: if test ! -d /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [d80966a6] Finished in 0.056 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [1b785133] Running ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile as deployer@45.56.119.188
DEBUG [1b785133] Command: cd /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310 && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [1b785133]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [1b785133]    LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/ssh
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-1.35.0/lib/fog/joyent/compute.rb:3:in `require'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-1.35.0/lib/fog/joyent/compute.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-1.35.0/lib/fog/joyent.rb:1:in `require'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-1.35.0/lib/fog/joyent.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-1.35.0/lib/fog.rb:41:in `require'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-1.35.0/lib/fog.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:3:in `require'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/storage.rb:9:in `require'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/storage.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:78:in `require'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:78:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/Rakefile:5:in `require'
DEBUG [1b785133]    /home/deployer/programservices/releases/20151209131310/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [1b785133]    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployer@45.56.119.188: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/ssh

...
```

Despite the error at the end, it *does* actually transfer the application into the "releases" folder. The new version files are there, but server is still running old app.

Comment: could you attach the log?

Comment: @richfisher attached log

Comment: Looks like bundler is failing on `Could not find fog-aliyun-0.0.10 in any of the sources` so something funky with this Gem. Maybe try and login to the server and manually run bundle and troubleshoot from there.

Comment: @Lumbee Thanks. I've updated Gemfile to use newest fog-aliyun, however the problem persists. Updated the log output above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I got it working. Capistrano is deploying to the Linode box and the "current" app becomes the newly deployed version. This was a huge pain in the butt. What worked were these things:

1. Comment-out the following lines in Capfile (as seen in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599986/capistrano-3-rails-4-database-configuration-does-not-specify-adapter)):

   ```
   #require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
   #require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
   ```

and put this line in

```
    require 'capistrano/rails'
```

2. **bundle update** on the following gems:

   - sshkit
   - carrierwave
   - fog
   - fog-aliyun
3. Reinstall **rbenv** on my local (Ubuntu 14.04) machine:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install rbenv
   ```
4. Set a "custom path" in the **deploy.rb** to point to rbenv on remote linode vps (also Ubu 14.04):

   ```
   set :rbenv_custom_path, '/home/deployer/.rbenv'
   ```

I hope some of these steps I took will help someone. Being new to Capistrano, I find it to be significantly lacking in documentation and have sympathy for those using it.